# MySQL inner join limit 1 row from second table

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have 2 (MySQL) tables , exchange table can have 1--n rows in exchitems, when an exchange record has multiple rows, I would like to display the word "multi", but when there is only 1 row, I would like to display the row's details:
First table (exchange):

```
xid (PK) | cusid | xdate      | xref   | xtotal
1        | 1     | 2021-10-01 | 345667 | 500
2        | 1     | 2021-10-01 | 345668 | 200
3        | 1     | 2021-10-02 | 345669 | 450
4        | 1     | 2021-10-03 | 345670 | 1200
```

And the second table (exchitems):

```
chid (PK) | xid | cusid | xcur| xsell| xbuy
1         | 1   | 1     | USD | 300  | 0
2         | 1   | 1     | EUR | 0    | 400
3         | 2   | 1     | USD | 200  | 0
4         | 3   | 1     | EUR | 0    | 500
5         | 4   | 1     | EUR | 0    | 800
6         | 4   | 1     | USD | 300  | 0
```

The **exchange** table must have at least 1 row in **exchtiems** table, and this is what I would like to get:

```
xid | cusid | xdate      | xref   | xcur  | xsell | xbuy | xtotal
1   | 1     | 2021-10-01 | 345667 | multi | 0     | 0    | 500
2   | 1     | 2021-10-01 | 345668 | USD   | 200   | 0    | 200
3   | 1     | 2021-10-02 | 345669 | EUR   | 0     | 500  | 450
4   | 1     | 2021-10-03 | 345670 | multi | 0     | 0    | 1200
```

Using the following query, i am able to get the all records, but I would like to limit the exchitems table to one row "any row" when there are multiple rows, the count is used to display the word "multi" when it is > 1:

```
SELECT a.xid,a.xdate,a.xref,a.xtotal,b.xcur,b.xsell,b.xbuy,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exchitems c WHERE c.xid= a.xid) AS tRec
FROM (exchange a 
INNER JOIN exchitems b ON a.xid= b.xid AND a.cusid= b.cusid)  
WHERE a.cusid = 1 
ORDER BY a.xdate DESC,a.xid DESC
```

I have tried many different queries but couldn't achieve what I want.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `GROUP BY xid` and `COUNT(chid)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this *should* work.

```
SELECT
    a.xid,
    a.cusid,
    a.xdate,
    a.xref,
    -- if distinct currency in the group is > 1 then the word 'multi', else currency.
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT b.xcur) > 1, 'multi', b.xcur) AS `xcur`,
    b.xsell,
    b.xbuy,
    a.xtotal
FROM exchange a
JOIN exchitems b ON a.xid = b.xid AND a.cusid = b.cusid
WHERE a.cusid = 1
GROUP BY xid -- will let you have exchange rows with groups of exchitems 1:n
ORDER BY a.xdate DESC, a.xid DESC
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the quick reply, I think the GROUP BY might do the trick, I have to test it on large scale, I think the "IF(COUNT(DISTINCT b.xcur) > 1, 'multi', b.xcur) AS `xcur`" should be "IF(COUNT(b.chid) > 1, 'multi', b.xcur) AS `xcur`".

Comment: @Alan If f.e. 2 rows joined from the `exchitems` tbl got the same currency 
then `COUNT(DISTINCT b.xcur)` should return 1. So there would be NOT multiple currencies =)

Comment: using COUNT(b.chid) will work on all cases as there are situations where the same currency is repeated!.

Comment: Hm, i thought you just want to show `multi` if there are multiple **different** currencies. I mean i know you wrote that you want if > 1, but in my book the same currency x n is still the same currency :D EDIT: but i see - ofc you want the other rows too. So yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your current query to the following:

```
SELECT a.xid, a.cusid, a.xdate,
       a.xref,
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.xcur),
       MIN(b.xsell),
       MIN(b.xbuy),
       MAX(a.xtotal)
FROM (exchange a 
INNER JOIN exchitems b ON a.xid= b.xid AND a.cusid= b.cusid)  
WHERE a.cusid = 1 
GROUP BY a.xid,a.cusid,a.xdate,a.xref
ORDER BY a.xid;
```

The result will look like this:

| xid | cusid | xdate | xref | GROUP_CONCAT(b.xcur) | MIN(b.xsell) | MIN(b.xbuy) | MAX(a.xtotal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 345667 | USD,EUR | 0 | 0 | 500 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 345668 | USD | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-10-02 | 345669 | EUR | 0 | 500 | 450 |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-10-03 | 345670 | EUR,USD | 0 | 0 | 1200 |

The part where I use `MIN` and `MAX` is according to your expected result. You may want to clarify which value to show there is you have multiple value. If I change that to `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
 SELECT a.xid, a.cusid, a.xdate,
        a.xref,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.xcur),
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.xsell),
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.xbuy),
        GROUP_CONCAT(a.xtotal)
 FROM (exchange a 
 INNER JOIN exchitems b ON a.xid= b.xid AND a.cusid= b.cusid)  
 WHERE a.cusid = 1 
 GROUP BY a.xid,a.cusid,a.xdate,a.xref
 ORDER BY a.xid;
```

Then you'll see a more elaborate result:

| xid | cusid | xdate | xref | GROUP_CONCAT(b.xcur) | GROUP_CONCAT(b.xsell) | GROUP_CONCAT(b.xbuy) | GROUP_CONCAT(a.xtotal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 345667 | USD,EUR | 300,0 | 0,400 | 500,500 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 345668 | USD | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-10-02 | 345669 | EUR | 0 | 500 | 450 |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-10-03 | 345670 | EUR,USD | 0,300 | 800,0 | 1200,1200 |

To make the `xcur` value show `multi`, you probably can do something like:

```
SELECT a.xid, a.cusid, a.xdate,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(b.xcur) > 1 THEN 'multi' ELSE MAX(b.xcur) END AS xcur,
       MIN(b.xsell),
       MIN(b.xbuy),
       MAX(a.xtotal)
FROM (exchange a 
INNER JOIN exchitems b ON a.xid= b.xid AND a.cusid= b.cusid)  
WHERE a.cusid = 1 
GROUP BY a.xid,a.cusid,a.xdate,a.xref
ORDER BY a.xid;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e98d9fed7cb690da693d2df43104d08)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I wish I could accept both answers, not sure if it is possible, had to give it to @cottton as he replied first. much appreciated

Comment: It's ok, however on MySQL server version 5.7 and above, @cotton's query won't work if the default `sql_mode` setting; which is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is retained. Refer [this fiddle test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=85b85ffc5f691fb09296a08e23f04705). And it is recommended to keep the setting `ON`, I quote _"the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want"_ from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)